# Consul crud operation commands for delete and get all

Tags: consul

I have consul entries in my kubernetes cluster. I need to perform CRUD operations. These are the commands I know, but I need to Get all and Delete and this has to be done with HTTP requests and **not with consul cli.**

> GET     - curl -k -X GET /?token=
>
> GET ALL -
>
> CREATE/PUT - curl -k --request PUT --data '' /?token=
>
> DELETE -

can someone please help me to find those two empty commands?

Answer (score 0):

I provided an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61491161/12384224 on how you can retrieve all values from Consul's KV store.

Consul's [KV Store](https://www.consul.io/api/kv.html) API docs contain `curl` examples for creating and deleting a given key. Take a look at Consul's [Transaction](https://www.consul.io/api/txn.html) API documentation if you are looking for a way to create and delete keys en-masse.