# Consul HTTP requests to get all kv values

Tags: consul, consul-kv

I need to get all the `consul` kv values using http api. Currently I can get the one value with the following command.

```
curl -k -X GET https://consul.banuka1.us-east-2.test:8543/v1/kv/banuka-test/test-value?token=1995-08-18
```

it returns only the value specified in it (`test-value`)

**But I want to get all the values in the `kv store`**

How can I do this? Is there a workaround here?

NOTE: I have already done this using `consul` cli but I want to do this with `https api`

Answer (score 15):

You can simplify this and reduce the number of API calls by using the [`recurse=true`](https://www.consul.io/api/kv.html#recurse) query argument.

```sh
curl http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/kv/\?recurse=true | jq -r '.[].Value | @base64d'
```

Answer (score 6):

I usually do this to print all the keys and values.

`v1/kv/?keys` - returns all the keys

I then iterate each key and read the raw response and decode the base64 value.

```sh
while read -r key
do    
    value=`curl --silent "http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/kv/$key" | jq -r '.[].Value' | base64 --decode`
    echo "$key - $value"
done < <(curl --silent "http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/kv/?keys"| jq -r '.[]')
```